# Get AD (Domain detals) on ADFS Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, adfs

I have three AD to authenticate user with ADFS using OpenIDConnect and MCV.net.
I am trying to find the details (specifically domain) from which AD user is logged in.

[image]

Comment: ADFS isn't related to Azure, it's the federation service used to authenticate across multiple domains. It has nothing to do with Open ID and doesn't need Azure authentication screens. In fact, if a browser is configured correctly, you wouldn't even get a popup while trying to connect to a web site on a different domain.

Comment: I suspect your actual question is how to use Azure AD in an ASP.NET MVC application? Did you check the Azure AD docs? Check the [Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp) tutorial

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry If I might have not presented question correctly, But I am already using ADFS authentication. I have couple of on-premises AD's. And I can authenticate user respectively. I have difficulty knowing from which AD user has logged in.
For eg. In above image user clicks on “Cloud ddns” and logs in then I need to find out its domain name (or something else from which I could differentiate those AD’s)